# Identifying Pygame KEYDOWN event

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating the game 2048 and am very early in the process but have already hit an issue that has completely stumped me.
Here is my main function (ignore the indentation being wrong, i'm new to stackoverflow)

```
def main():

while True:

    #Process input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            closeGame()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == keyESC:
            closeGame()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == keyLEFT:
            gameArray[3][2] = 1

    drawGame()
```

I expected after pressing my left button (which is being defined elsewhere with `keyLEFT = (pygame.K_LEFT)` ) to change the variable mentioned in `gameArray[3][2] = 1`.

Then I have this function to draw the game

```
def drawGame():
screen.fill(WHITE)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0, 0, 450, 450), 0)
# Printing the rows
for i in range (4):
    # Printing the cells
    for j in range (4):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, getColour(gameArray[i][j]), (tileGAP + ((tileSPACE) * j), tileGAP + (tileSPACE * i), tileWIDTH, tileWIDTH), 0)


pygame.display.flip()
```

My question is why isnt the square of gameArray[3][2] being changed after the left key is pressed?
Sorry if i have set this up really badly, im new to this.

Comment: Where are you declaring gameArray? This could be a scope issue where gameArray is declared inside one particular function and other functions can't access it or modify it.

Comment: right at the very start of the program, before any functions are even defined

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing "keyLEFT" with "pygame.K_LEFT" per [pygame documentation](https://pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html).

Also see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593200/pygame-keydown-event-and-key-events)